# How do I create a linked reference to a page that is an arbitrary number of pages after a specific label?

Tags: context, context-lmtx

I am typesetting a ConTeXt document that contains an addendum of included PDFs (using `\copypages`). I've added labels to the first page of each included PDF in the addendum using `\reference`. I would like to add links to the addendum in the body of my document. If I'm referring to the first page of a particular PDF (labeled `add:pdf1`, for example), I can simply use a command like `\at` (e.g., `\at{Add.}[add:pdf1]` to produce a linked reference "Add. 12"). What if I want to refer to the second (or third, or fourth) page of an included PDF?

I've been able to get ConTeXt to print the page of the second page of a referenced PDF using the following command: `\the\numexpr\ref[page][add:pdf1]+1\relax`. How can I make this a clickable link too?

Here is a MWE:

```
\setupinteraction[state=start]

\starttext

Please see page 1 of the PDF in the addendum. \at{Add.}[add:pdf1].

Please see page 2 of the PDF in the addendum. Add.\ \the\numexpr\ref[page][add:pdf1]+1\relax.

\page[yes]

\reference[add:pdf1]{Pdf1}
This is page 1 of the PDF Pdf1.

\page[yes]

This is page 2 of the PDF Pdf1.

\page[yes]

This is page 3 of the PDF Pdf1.

\stoptext
```

In the output (displayed below), I would like both "Add. #" references to be linked to the appropriate page. Using the approach I've used in the MWE, only the first reference is linked.

[image: Output of first page of MWE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the easiest thing is to loop yourself. In the example below, the `230825-1` is a three pages long document that want to include in `230825-2`.

`230825-1`:

```
\setuppagenumbering
  [state=stop]

\starttext

\chapter[title=Knuth]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=color,backgroundcolor=red]
\samplefile{knuth}

\chapter[title=Ward]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=color,backgroundcolor=green]
\samplefile{ward}

\chapter[title=Tufte]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=color,backgroundcolor=yellow]
\samplefile{tufte}

\stoptext
```

`230825-2`:

```
\setupinteraction
  [state=start]

\starttext

\at[foo:1], \at[foo:2], \at[foo:3].

\dostepwiserecurse{1}{3}{1}{
  \startTEXpage[pagestate=start]
    \reference
      [foo:#1]{}%
    \externalfigure
      [230825-1]
      [page=#1,
       offset=overlay]
  \stopTEXpage
}

% % Or alternatively:
%
% \setupfittingpage[pagestate=start]
%
% \dostepwiserecurse{1}{3}{1}{
%   \startpagefigure[230825-1][page=#1]
%     \reference[foo:#1]{}\blank[-line]%
%   \stoppagefigure
% }

This goes on its own page.

\stoptext
```

`230825-2.pdf` looks something like this:

[image: result]

Note that on the first page, we have links to the three different pages, and the text after goes to the next page (which becomes page 5). You can turn this into a macro if you need it in more places.

**Update (after question in comment)**

If you want to calculate the number of pages, you can do it like this:

```
\setupinteraction
  [state=start]

\starttext

\at[foo:1], \at[foo:2], \at[foo:3].

\getfiguredimensions[230825-1.pdf]
\dostepwiserecurse{1}{\noffigurepages}{1}{
  \startTEXpage[pagestate=start]
    \reference
      [foo:#1]{}%
    \externalfigure
      [230825-1]
      [page=#1,
       offset=overlay]
  \stopTEXpage
}

This goes on its own page.

\stoptext
```

Output is the same.

Comment: Thank you! When I use \dostepwiserecurse, it appears I need to hard-code the number of pages in the PDF to be included. Is there a relatively easy way for me to have ConTeXt determine the number of pages for me to use in \dostepwiserecurse?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you set `crossreference=yes`, then ConTeXt will automatically make references with the (inscrutable) names `cross:b:ex:page number`:

```tex
\setupinteraction[state=start]

\setupexternalfigures[
    location=global,
    directory={/opt/context/tex/texmf-context/doc/context/documents/general/manuals/},
]

\setupheader[state=empty]

\starttext
    See page~15 of the \LuaMetaTeX\ manual (\at{page}[cross:b:ex:15]).\page

    \dorecurse{9}{filler page\page}

    \copypages[luametatex.pdf][n=30][crossreference=yes]

    \dorecurse{10}{filler page\page}
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's a really clean solution that avoids the arithmetic I would otherwise need to do.

Do you know how I would go about referring to one of several PDFs that I've included using \copypages? For example, I will have anywhere from 2 to 10 PDFs in the addendum. Is there another (inscrutable) way to refer to the second PDF included by \copypages, for example?

Comment: @J.King You can make a feature request on the ConTeXt mailing list to have proper support for hyperlinks to images, e.g. `\externalfigure[...][reference=...]` and `\copypages[...][reference=...]`.